# this.smtpServersettings is sending mail to undelivered options instead of gmail

Tags: coldfusion, cfmail, coldfusion-2018

I want to send a email to real gmail ID's to the end users. So I used **smtp.gmail.com** as mail server with my own email user name & password. But if I use **this.smtpServersettings** in my application.cfc it's not sending a email. All the mail's are went to undelivered options. My sample code,
**App.cfc :**

```
<cfset this.name='mailfn8'>
<cfset this.smtpServersettings={server:"smtp.gmail.com",username:"mygmail@gmail.com",password:"mypassword"}>
```

**My.cfm :**

```
<cfmail from='sender@gmail.com' to='receiver@gmail.com' subject='test' type='html' port="587" usetls="true">
    I'm seding a email by using this.smtpServersettings options.
</cfmail>
```

But the credentials are working great in below scenario,

```
-- If I set my details in application scope and use that values in cfmail tag
-- Directly set it in coldfusion mail server setting
```

For example,
**App.cfc :**

```
<cfset this.name='mailfn8'>
<cffunction name='onApplicationStart'>

    <cfset application.server='smtp.gmail.com'>
    <cfset application.username='mygmail@gmail.com'>
    <cfset application.password='mypassword'>

</cffunction>
```

**My.cfm :**

```
<cfmail from='sender@gmail.com' to='receiver@gmail.com' server= '#application.server#' username='#application.userName#' password='#application.password#' subject='test' type='html' port="587" usetls="true">
    I'm seding a email by using application scope.
</cfmail>
```

The above working fine. **So why this.smtpServersettings is send email to undelivered option instead of gmail. ?** .Do I need to enable any other setting if I use this.smtpServerSetting ?  Please help me on this.  Correct me if I'm understood anything wrong.  Thank you !.

Answer (score 3):

The smtpServerSettings struct does not support port and usetls.

https://tracker.adobe.com/#/view/CF-4204467

My suggestion is to create your own struct in application scope then pass to cfmail tag with argumentCollection attribute.

Comment: Thanks for your confirmation @Dan Roberts. So that I mentioned it was working fine as passing directly the value or as structure as well.